# How to manipulate a list item from it's view in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application with both a view and a controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/gavriguy/EDr4G/

I want to mark the current item the user clicks as read - by changing it's related model.
I'm currently able to do that by figuring the item's index of the view - but the problem is that i can't be sure that the index on the view is the same as the index on its controller.
Any thoughts?

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.tempController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        {
        title: 'A',
        unread: true},
    {
        title: 'B',
        unread: true},
    {
        title: 'C',
        unread: false}
    ]
});

App.someItemsView = Ember.CollectionView.create({
    contentBinding: 'App.tempController.content',
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div>{{content.title}} unread: {{content.unread}}</div>'),
        click: function(event) {
            //How to mark current clicked item as read?
            console.log(this.content);
            console.log(event);
            this.set('content.unread', false);
        }
    })
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `click` handler you can get the reference to the array item for which the view is rendered via `this.get('content')`. So you can set the flag via `this.setPath('content.unread', false)`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/t6Nst/:

```js
itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div>{{content.title}} unread: {{content.unread}}</div>'),
    click: function(event) {
        // this.content is the item in the array on which this click event occures.
        this.setPath('content.unread', false);
    }
})
```